IMO 1998 Number Theory
Problem: Determine all pairs $(a,b)$ $\in\mathbb{N\times N}$ such that $ab^2+b+7 \mid a^2b+a+b$.

Attempt:
Since $ab^2+b+7$ divides $a^2b+a+b$ we can write this as $a^2b+a+b=k\cdot(ab^2+b+7)$
This is equivalent to $7k-b=(ab-1)(a-kb)$
I am stuck at this point. Could someone give me a hint?
Thank you!

AoPS has a full solution.

@AnneBauval  Yes, I have started casework and I think I got it.
